# Python turtle graphics stop responding

Tags: python

When I run the code, the input window shows and I enter the number of squares. After that, the python turtle graphics stop responding and then disappear without showing anything.

Here's my code:

```
#
import turtle
from random import randint
turtle.tracer(0)
turtle.bgcolor('black')
#Takes user input to decide how many squares are needed
f=int(input("How many squares do you want?"))

i=1

x=65

#Draws the desired number of squares.
while i < f:
    i=i+1
    x=x*1.05
    while x<400 :
      r=randint(0,255)
      g=randint(0,255)
      b=randint(0,255)
      turtle.colormode(255)
      turtle.pencolor(r,g,b)
      turtle.bk(x)
      turtle.rt(90)
      turtle.bk(x)
      turtle.rt(90)
      turtle.bk(x)
      turtle.rt(90)
      turtle.bk(x)
      turtle.rt(90)
      turtle.up()
      turtle.rt(9)
      turtle.down()
turtle.update()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move `turtle.update()` in the loop and add `break`, so after the number of squares are drawn, the window stops updating.

```
import turtle
from random import randint
turtle.tracer(0)
turtle.bgcolor('black')
#Takes user input to decide how many squares are needed
f=int(input("How many squares do you want?"))

i=1

x=65

#Draws the desired number of squares.
while i < f:
    i=i+1
    x=x*1.05
    while x<400 :
      r=randint(0,255)
      g=randint(0,255)
      b=randint(0,255)
      turtle.colormode(255)
      turtle.pencolor(r,g,b)
      turtle.bk(x)
      turtle.rt(90)
      turtle.bk(x)
      turtle.rt(90)
      turtle.bk(x)
      turtle.rt(90)
      turtle.bk(x)
      turtle.rt(90)
      turtle.up()
      turtle.rt(9)
      turtle.down()
      turtle.update()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: use a `for` loop for looping a known amount of times (they are also faster), also `i = i + 1` -> `i += 1`; `x = x * 1.05` -> `x *= 1.05` and I would suggest following PEP 8 and have space around operators (such as `=`)